# How to get values out from a interface callback method

Tags: android

I have this callback method where i want to get list of string value return , so i can use it furthur

```
   public List<String> ProfileHtmlGetList(String linkUrl){
        List<String> htmlListProfile = new ArrayList<>();
    ProfileHtml(linkUrl, metadataList -> {
            htmlListProfile.addAll(metadataList);
    });
    return htmlListProfile;
}
```

and here is the Method ProfileHtml

```
 public void ProfileHtml (String url, MetadataCallback callback) {
        ExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
        Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());

        executor.execute(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                List<String> metadataList = new ArrayList<>();

                try {
                    Document document = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
                    Elements metaTags = document.getElementsByTag("meta");

                    for (Element metaTag : metaTags) {
                        String property = metaTag.attr("property");
                        String content = metaTag.attr("content");

                        if (property.equals("og:description")) {
                            metadataList.add(content);
                        }

                        if (property.equals("og:image")) {
                            content = content.replace("&amp;", "&");
                            metadataList.add(content);
                        }
                    }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                handler.post(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        callback.onMetadataReady(metadataList); // Pass the result back to the caller
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    }
```

im not getting any data in htmlListProfile , when returned from ProfileHtmlGetList